# Bootstrapping a list of concretes using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have a class that takes in several types of Interfaces, all which inherit from interface `IVehicle`. I am using Simple Injector for IOC.  The class I currently have looks something like this.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ICar car, IMotorcycle motorcycle)
    {              
    }
}
```

However, I am trying to get rid of passing each type of IVehicle and just pass in a list of IVehicle. The list containing the ICar and IMotorcycle interfaces. So my desired class would look something like this.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IEnumerable<IVehicle> vehicles)
    {

    }
}
```

I have the modification of the class down but I'm not sure how to bootstrap this in order for it to pass in all the IVehicles types.

I tried doing something like this in bootstrapping.

```
<IEnumerable<IVehicle>, List<IVehicle>>
```

However, in my class when I look at my list it is empty. Does anyone know how I can go about making that list be populated with my `IVehicle` types(ICar, IMotorcycle)?

Comment: Why not have a vehicles class which has a IEnumerable of IVehicles and create an interface for iVehicles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#collections) states:

> Simple Injector contains several methods for registering and resolving collections of types. Here are some examples:
>
> ```
> // Configuration
> // Registering a list of instances that will be created by the container.
> // Supplying a collection of types is the preferred way of registering collections.
> container.RegisterCollection<ILogger>(new[] { typeof(MailLogger), typeof(SqlLogger) });
>
> [...]
>
> // Usage
> var loggers = container.GetAllInstances<ILogger>();
> ```

Translated to your case this means:

```
container.RegisterCollection<IVehicle>(new[] { typeof(Car), typeof(Motorcycle) });
```